# Change width of all elements whose id starts with 'change' using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple div elements on an ASPX page. Each of these div elements has ids like 'changeHeader' or 'changeFooter' or 'changeHeaderImg' and so on. I want to write jQuery which will change the width to 90% for all such divs. Right now the width of each of these divs is set to 70%. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/rWnww/)**

```
$('div[id^="change"]').css('width', '90%');
```

For both div and span

```
$('div[id^="change"], span[id^="change"]').css('width', '90%');
```

For any type of element having id starting with `change`

```
$('[id^="change"]').css('width', '90%');
```

Comment: Adil. Thanks. Actually some elements may be not div but a span. Can I just mention * in place of div so we have $('*[id^="change"]')?

Comment: @Sunil yes you can use that selector instead, which is same as `$('[id^="change"]')` without universal selector `*`. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
 $("[id^='change']").css("width","90%");
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, use `$('div[id=^"change"]').css('width', '90%');`